# Upgrade to OS X 10.7 Lion and Xcode 4 with low disk space

Tags: macos, upgrade, osx-lion, xcode

I want to upgrade to OS X Lion (from 10.6.8) but only have 2.5 GB free on my system disk.

I also want to upgrade to XCode 4, so I have 10 GB in /Developer that I might be able to trash (though I'm a little nervous about that).

**How much more storage space does 10.7+Xcode 4 use than 10.6.8+Xcode 3.2.5?**

I have an external drive with a bunch of space on it if that helps.